# i am getting this error java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-03-09T18:30:00.000Z"

Tags: java, dateformatter

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
String dateStr = "2017-03-09T18:30:00.000Z";
Date date = formatter.parse(dateStr);
System.out.println("here");
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Sure. Note the sparkles in your pattern!

Comment: Thanks i got the problem is was missing 'Z'. Z should be in single quote as T

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks i got the problem is was missing 'Z'. Z should be in single
> quote as T

No! No! No!

Using `'Z'` in the pattern will make `Z` treated as a character literal instead of as its intended meaning. The `Z` in the date-time string, `2017-03-09T18:30:00.000Z` is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Moreover, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>  is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the date-time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.parse("2017-03-09T18:30:00.000Z");
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2017-03-09T18:30:00Z
```

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `Instant` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Using the legacy API:**

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API. Just for the sake of completeness, I have written below a solution using the legacy date-time API.

Use `X` to handle the `Z` in your date-time string. Check the [documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to learn more about the symbols.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d'T'H:m:s.SSSX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdf.parse("2017-03-09T18:30:00.000Z");
        System.out.println(date);// Note: will display date-time in your local timezone
    }
}
```

**Output in my timezone:**

```
Thu Mar 09 18:30:00 GMT 2017
```

Note that the `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the date-time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` and obtain the formatted string from it e.g.

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>